# Jboss Fuse start issue: cannot connect to client

Tags: windows-7, jbossfuse

I'm running JBoss Fuse version 6.3.0.redhat-187 on Windows 7 64-bit and I start the Fuse service on the background with the `bin/start` command, but when I try to run a client with `bin/client` command I get a "Failed to get the session" as a result. I tried running `bin/client -h localhost` but get the same problem. Any ideas for why this is happening?

Comment: Can you access your installation with a regular SSH client like Putty? Usually the port is 8101

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna I run Putty with hostname "localhost" and port 8101 in SSH and I get "Network error: Connection Refused".

Comment: looks like your JBoss Fuse is not running. What if you open `http://localhost:8181` with a browser? This should load JBoss web console. Do you see java.exe in Windows Task Manager? What does JBoss Fuse log says? (file `data/log/fuse.log`)

Comment: Now it works, but I have to type and run `start.bat` in the windows shell. I tried running `start` before because the `fuse` command works fine without the `.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

please check whether fuse is started sucessfully or not using  using /bin/status
you can also cross check whether fuse process has successfully started or not using taskmanager

uncomment users from users.properties file and try to connect using

./client -u username -p password